# What is tree conflict in svn?

Tags: svn, merge, tree-conflict

I am on svn 1.7.4/  and tortoise svn 1.7.6.
I tried to google what is `What is tree conflict in svn` but could not get some article which explains it in depth except some specific questions.

**Here is my understanding on tree conflict**

Say I have trunk, now I created the branch branch1 out of trunk at time  T1. Now if some developer adds some file or folder or renames some file under trunk at T2 and when i try to merge the branch to trunk (using `Merge using range of revisions`), I will get the tree conflict because of addition of some file or folder in source (trunk in this case) . Is that right ?  If yes what is the way to merge changes back to trunk preferably using Tortoise SVN?

While if addition/deletion/rename happens on branch after T1 but trunk does not get changed, will i still get the Tree conflict?
If yes what is the way to resolve it preferably using Tortoise SVN?

Comment: Good search string will be "tree conflict SVN" and it will give you authoritative sources even in first results

Answer (score 1):

Not every edit|delete|add in future merge-nodes will produce tree-conflict

Read carefully:

1. [Dealing with Structural Conflicts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html) in SVN Book
2. [Tree Conflicts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html#tsvn-dug-conflicts-tree) in TortoiseSVN docs
3. [Subversion 1.6.0 and Tree Conflicts](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/subversion-160-and-tree-conflicts) in CollabNet blog